Anyone know how to render cycles animations faster?
So i've been using blender for a couple months now and i'm starting to get into using cycles for my renders. As fun as it is, it's taking a long time to render and I was hoping someone could help me figure out why and a way to make the render process shorter. Below is what I have been using to render cycles. Please let me know if theres anything I can do

